# AdminLTE Expand or Fullscreen boxes

Tags: javascript, css, adminlte

`AdminLTE` an Admin template based on `Bootstrap`.

I'm wondering if I can make `box-widget` to expand to a full screen mode (second button).

> [image]

I'm looking if there is any CSS class or JavaScript tip to make this to work.

I didn't find such thing in `AdminLTE` docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also ran into the same problem today.
I did it this way.

HTML

```
<button type="button" class="toggle-expand-btn btn bg-yellow btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-expand"></i></button>
```

CSS

```
<style>
.panel-fullscreen {
display: block;
z-index: 9999;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
overflow: auto;
}
</style>
```

JS

```
$(".toggle-expand-btn").click(function (e) {
  $(this).closest('.box.box-warning').toggleClass('panel-fullscreen');
});
```

Change the box and the button class according to your need and it will be fixed.
Hope it will works.

Answer (score 0):

An open box: `<div class="box">`

A collapsed box: `<div class="box collapsed-box">`

And then ofcourse change the icon on the button

Comment: i already have the  open/collapsed mode, i'm looking for switching the widget in full screen, i'm wondering to show the content of my widget in full page

Answer (score -1):

You can use Bootstrap Class for getting full screen mode.

Comment: which Bootstrap class ?

Comment: col-xs-12 / col-md-12